# spaCy: custom infix regex rule to split on `:` for patterns like mailto:johndoe@gmail.com is not applied consistently

Tags: tokenize, spacy

With the default tokenizer, spaCy treats `mailto:johndoe@gmail.com` as one single token.

I tried the following:

`nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
infixes = nlp.Defaults.infixes + (r'(?<=mailto):(?=\w+)', )
nlp.tokenizer.infix_finditer = spacy.util.compile_infix_regex(infixes).finditer`

However, the above custom rule doesn't seem to do what I would like to do in a consistent matter. For example, if I apply the tokenizer to `mailto:johndoe@gmail.c`, it does what I want:

```
nlp("mailto:johndoe@gmail.c")
# [mailto, :, johndoe@gmail.c]
```

However, if I apply the tokenizer to `mailto:johndoe@gmail.com`, it does not work as intended.

```
nlp("mailto:johndoe@gmail.com")
# [mailto:johndoe@gmail.com]
```

I wonder if there is a way to fix this inconsistency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a tokenizer exception pattern for URLs, which matches things like `mailto:johndoe@gmail.com` as one token. It knows that top-level domains have at least two letters so it matches `gmail.co` and `gmail.com` but not `gmail.c`.

You can override it by setting:

```
nlp.tokenizer.token_match = None
```

Then you should get:

```
[t.text for t in nlp("mailto:johndoe@gmail.com")]
# ['mailto', ':', 'johndoe@gmail.com']

[t.text for t in nlp("mailto:johndoe@gmail.c")]
# ['mailto', ':', 'johndoe@gmail.c']
```

If you want the URL tokenization to be as by default except for `mailto:`, you could modify the `URL_PATTERN` from `lang/tokenizer_exceptions.py` (also see how  `TOKEN_MATCH` is defined right below it) and use that rather than `None`.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question again! I will just use the build in `LIKE_URL` functionality --  I didn't know `LIKE_URL` would recognize `mailto:` patterns as well.